# Enhancing a queryset's performance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm learning DRF and experimenting with a queryset. I'm trying to optimize to work as efficiently as possible. **The goal being to get a list of grades for active students who are majoring in 'Art'.**

Based on [database optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/) techniques,
I've ran some different updates and don't see a difference when I look at the Time returned via the console's Network tab. I DO however, see less logs in the Seq scan when I run the .explain() method on the model filtering. **Am I accomplishing anything by doing that?**

For example: 
Grades.objects.filter(student_id__in=list(student_list)).order_by()

**Anything else I can do to improve the below code that I might be missing? - Outside of adding any Foreign or Primary key model changes.**

```
class GradeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GradesSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        active_students = Student.objects.filter(active=True)
        student_list = active_students.filter(major='Art').values_list('student_id')
        queryset = Grades.objects.filter(student_id__in=student_list)

        serializers = GradesSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

SQL query I'm attempting to create in Django.

```
select * from app_grades g
join app_students s on g.student_id = s.student_id
where s.active = true and s.major = 'Art'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will execute two separate database queries, I suggest that you try the following query instead:

```
queryset = Grades.objects.filter(student__active=True, student__major='Art')
```

this code will retrieve the exact same records but performing only one query with the appropriate `JOIN` clause.

You probably want to take a look at [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Because of the lack of model relations that forbids the use of lookups I suggest that you use an [Exists subuery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries). In this specific case the query will be as follows:

```
queryset = Grades.objects.annotate(student_passes_filter=Exists(
    Student.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('student_id'), active=True, major='Art')
)).filter(student_passes_filter=True)
```

You will need to import `Exists` and `OuterRef`. Note that these are available from Django 1.11 onwards.

Comment: Getting an error -> "Cannot resolve keyword 'student' into field". Choices are:... It's only displaying the fields from the Grades model. Am I missing a step? I'm assuming it's because I don't have proper relationships in my models. Just CharFields with student_ids, etc.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not having proper relationships between your models?

Comment: Not a good reason. Just replicating a real world issue where the models cannot be changed.

Comment: Ok then, I've updated my answer considering this new scenario. Anyway, I would consider defining the proper relation in django, specially if you plan to add more complex queries. If you truly can't modify models, then maybe adding an [unmanaged model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed) with the desired relationships is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably regroup those lines to reduce the number of queries:

```
active_students = Student.objects.filter(active=True)
student_list = active_students.filter(major='Art').values_list('student_id')
```

Into:

```
active_students = Student.objects.filter(active=True, major=‘Art’)
```

And converting to list then